# PHP - Cannot change session variable in an "if" statement

Tags: php, redirect

Trying to make a page redirect if not logged in. I'll try to show what I mean.

In the index.php:

```
<?php
// initialization of login system and generation code
$oSimpleLoginSystem = new SimpleLoginSystem();
echo $oSimpleLoginSystem->getLoginBox();
session_start();
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = False;

// class SimpleLoginSystem
class SimpleLoginSystem {

    // variables
    var $aExistedMembers; // Existed members array

    // constructor
    function SimpleLoginSystem() {
        $this->aExistedMembers = array(
            'test' => MD5('test'),  //Sample: MD5('qwerty')
        );
    }

    function getLoginBox() {
        ob_start();
        require_once('login_form.html');
        $sLoginForm = ob_get_clean();

        $sLogoutForm = '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?logout=1">logout</a>';

        if ((int)$_REQUEST['logout'] == 1) {
            if (isset($_COOKIE['member_name']) && isset($_COOKIE['member_pass']))
                $this->simple_logout();
        }

        if ($_REQUEST['username'] && $_REQUEST['password']) {
            if ($this->check_login($_REQUEST['username'], MD5($_REQUEST['password']))) 
            {
                $_SESSION["loggedin"] = True;
                $this->simple_login($_REQUEST['username'], $_REQUEST['password']);
                header( 'Location: /site.html' );
            } 
            else {
                return 'Username or Password is incorrect' . $sLoginForm;
            }
        } else {
            if ($_COOKIE['member_name'] && $_COOKIE['member_pass']) {
                if ($this->check_login($_COOKIE['member_name'], $_COOKIE['member_pass'])) {
                    header( 'Location: /site.html' );
                }
            }
            return $sLoginForm;
        }
    }
```

In the site.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION["loggedin"] == 0)
{

    header( 'Location: http://test-weeabear.c9users.io/' );
}

else
{
return "It worked!"
}
?>
```

Why is it when I open site.html, it redirects me back to index.html, even after logging in?

NOTE: Some things I changed, like links and names of files. For privacy.

Comment: write session_start() before if condition in site.php.

Comment: Still redirects me back. Dunno what's wrong.

Comment: is your header statement contains url of index.php in actual code? try to print $_SESSION with exit next to it and check what you are receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `session_start()` at the start of your `site.php`

Answer (score 1):

change the file extension from .html to .php

Comment: My bad, was supposed to be php.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling getLoginBox and then changing the loggedin back to false. You need to include an exit after the header redirect.

Like this:

```
header( 'Location: /site.php' );//changed to file extension as .php
exit;
```